# Как получить значение атрибута data-original-title

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Для парсинга использую simple html dom parser.
Есть такая разметка:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-timestamp="15555555" class="catalog_podarkov" data-original-title="10.08.2017 в 10:02">В 2017 году</span>
```

Мне нужно получить значение атрибута **data-original-title**

Обращаюсь к этому элементу так:

```
$dates = $catalog->find('.catalog_podarkov');
```

В итоге получаю `В 2017 году`

пробовал так:

```
$dates = $catalog->find('.catalog_podarkov');
$dates = $dates[0]->attr['data-original-title'];
```

В итоге ошибка:

```
Notice: Undefined index: data-original-title
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `$dates[0]->{data-original-title}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы проверяете что именно вы получили? PHP позволяет разработчикам реализовывать метод `__toString`, который вызывается **автоматически** при приведении объекта к строке (как например в случае `echo $dates;`). Если вы хотите во время отладки узнать, что находится в переменной, используйте `var_dump`.

Далее, из документации либы следует, что для доступа к атрибутам, надо дёргать одноимённые свойства найденных элементов. То есть:

```
$elements = $catalog->find('.catalog_podarkov'); // тут вы получаете коллекцию элементов, даже если элемент всего один
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->{'data-original-title'}; // синтаксис с фигурными скобками, позволяет обратиться к свойству с нестандартным именем
}
```

Код целиком, для невнимательных:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$html = '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-timestamp="15555555" class="catalog_podarkov" data-original-title="10.08.2017 в 10:02">В 2017 году</span>';
$dom = \Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($html);
$elements = $dom->find('.catalog_podarkov');
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->{'data-original-title'}, "\n";
}

// выводит 10.08.2017 в 10:02
```

Всё выдаёт.

Comment: так ничего не выдает

Comment: @Денис будте внимательны, всё выдаёт. Обновил ответ для вас.